# How to output combo box list values?

Tags: c#, extjs, combobox

I want to output the values from a combo box without selecting any of its' values. I can only get the value if a value is selected. Here's what I got so far:

```
var combo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=comboName]')[0];
combo.getRawValue();
```

Comment: Im not sure its clear what you're after. The items in a combo box are a type of Object and are displayed as strings.

Comment: How would I go about outputting those values without selecting a value first?

Comment: There is a property of a ComboBox called Items. This is a collection of everything in the combo box.

Comment: @CathalMF I dont' see that property in https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

Answer (score 1):

First, get the store of your combo box and use Stores each method to iterate through store and output the values.

```
var store = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=comboName]')[0].getStore();

store.each(function(record){
    //for each record you can output the value from store.
});
```

Comment: that only outputs the constructor, i need the fields in the constructor.

Comment: Get the fields from what you call "constructor" this way: `record.getData()`.

Comment: you can get RawValue of each record by `record[combobox.displayField]`.